# In which include file EPERM (returned by pthread_mutex_unlock) error code is declared?

Tags: include, pthreads, errno

Can anyone give me the right direction for this, as I am not able to find the declaration of EPERM in either pthread.h or errno.h (on openSUSE Linux). I found this in asm-generic/errno-base.h but is this the right one? Why its not in errno.h? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the right one. And it's in `errno.h`, though through a long chain of includes. For example on my linux development box `errno.h` includes `bits/errno.h` which includes `linux/errno.h` which includes `asm/errno.h` which includes a specific version of `asm-*/errno.h`, e.g. `asm-i386/errno.h`, which includes `asm-generic/errno.h` containing the `#define` for `EPERM`.